# At which step of the proof below I am making a mistake?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

$(a_n) \rightarrow 0 \implies \sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n \rightarrow L \;\;$ for some $L < \infty$

I know the above statement is false. A typical counterexample is  $a_n = \frac{1}{n} \;\;$. Yet, when I attempt to prove somehow I "prove" it. So I am doing a mistake in my proof but I couldn't figure out where. I was hoping someone can point out the mistake.

given $\forall \epsilon > 0, \; \exists N : \forall n > N, \; |a_n| < \epsilon$

I want to show that for $\;\; s_n = a_1 + ... + a_n \;\; ,\;\;\;\forall \epsilon > 0, \;\; |s_n - s_m| < \epsilon $

Without loss of generality assume that $n>m \;$ and $\;n = m+k\;$, then $\;\; |s_n - s_m| = |a_n + ... + a_{m+1}|$

Now, since $(a_n) \rightarrow 0 \;\;$, given $\epsilon >0\;$ pick $N^*>0$ such that  $\forall m> N^*, |a_m| < \frac{\epsilon}{k}$.

then let $n,m >N^*$:

$|s_n-s_m|  = |a_{m+k} + ... + a_{m+1}| \leq |a_{m+k} |+  ... + |a_{m+1}| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{k} + ... + \frac{\epsilon}{k} = k \frac{\epsilon}{k} = \epsilon $

I am depending the choice of $N^*$ also on the value $k(n,m)$. So if I pick another $n' > m+k$ then the above inequality fails. So this means the above argument only holds given $\forall m, m+k > N^* \;\;$ and $\forall k >0$? I am confused a bit of help on pointing out my mistake will be appreciated...

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\lim _{n \to \infty} a_n=0$$ in first line, because you said $a_n \rightarrow 0$ , but for what what $n$, as you took example $a_n = 1/n $ it doesn't tend zero if $n$ is finite

Comment: Note where in the proof you fix the value of n,m and thus may no longer change them. Hint: it happens before you have $N^*$, and that is the problem.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I am fixing $m < N^*, |a_m| < \frac{\epsilon}{k}$ then using the same $m$ with $n = m+k$ right below. So I am not changing the values of $n, m$ BUT I am fixing $n$ to $m+k$ is that where the problem arises as the final sets of inequalities should be valid for any choice of $n$? In a way my choice of $N^*$ can be redefined as $N_k$ and then the set of inequalities only applies $\forall n \leq m+k$, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful in the proof. You have to show the following:

For all $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N^*$ large enough, such that for all $n,m > N^*$, we have $|s_n - s_m| < \epsilon$.

First of all : WLOG, $n = m+k$, where $k$ isn't fixed, it can be any natural number.

You are saying the following : for the given $\epsilon$, there is $N^*$ such that $|a_m| < \frac{\epsilon}{k}$. **This certainly cannot hold for all $k$**, since then you are saying that $a_m = 0$ after $N^*$, which need not be the case  for example in the harmonic series. Hence, *$k$ is actually fixed by this statement*.

Now, $n,m > N^*$, then *provided $n=m+k$* (**remember, $k$ is fixed**!), we have that $|s_n-s_m| < \epsilon$.

However, the question arises : we need the equality *for all* $n,m$ which isn't true,  this is being provided only when the distance between them is fixed!

Hence, the argument is flawed.

To give an example: suppose we take the Harmonic series $\frac 1n$, and $ \epsilon = \frac 19$. Then, yes, we can find, for all $k$, a number $N^*$ depending on $k$, such that after $N^*$, the sum of $k$ consecutive terms is bounded by $\epsilon$. However, we can't say much if we are considering the sum of $1000k$ terms after $N^*$, for example.

Comment: So I only showed that the difference between two partial sums that are away from each other by k many elements (such as $s_n$ and $s_{n+k}$) can be as small as I want if I move "forward enough" on the series. In other words, $\forall \epsilon >0, \; \exists k \geq 0: \;\; \exists N_k >0: \forall m> N_k, |s_{m+k}-s_m| < \epsilon$ but this does not mean cauchy since for the series to be cauchy we needed $\forall k$.

Comment: @Cointegration No, the correct statement is as follows : $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\forall k > 0$, there is $N_k$ such that whenever $m > N_k$, $|s_{m+k} - s_m| < \epsilon$, so you do get a forall. The problem is, as you increase $k$, there is no guarantee that $N_k$ will stop increasing. If it does,excellent, your done, but if not, as in the case of the harmonic series, then you are done (and dusted).

Comment: Ok so you are saying that: in order for it to be valid, we needed $N_k$ to converge as $k \rightarrow \infty$. In other words, I can always find a difference that is small than some $\epsilon$ between two partial sums that are finitely away from each other, but this certainly does not mean that the partial sums converge (as I am not guaranteed to find two partial sums that infinitely away from each other that are arbitrarily small as in the case of harmonic series)

Comment: @Cointegration Given $\epsilon > 0$, you need the same $N_k$ to work for all $k$, because then $N_k$ doesn't depend on the difference between $n$ and $m$, so then it will hold $\forall n,m$.

Comment: Yes I fully understand now. Thanks a lot. The whole problem is due to my narrow understanding of cauchy sequences: I always envisioned cauchy sequences having some static m and n... Now the equivalence between cauchy and convergent series makes much more sense.

Comment: @Cointegration It's great we've got it cleared up. You are welcome.